# How randomized the order of characters of a password generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Currently the code only randomized in sequence , first letters then numbers and lastly symbols i would like it to randomized in any order without sequence , how to implement?

```
#Password Generator Project
import string
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
l_password = ""
s_password = ""
n_password = ""


# Eazy Level - Order not randomised:5

# e.g. 4 letter, 2 symbol, 2 number = JduE&!91

for letter in range(nr_letters):
  l_password += random.choice(letters)


for symbol in range(nr_symbols):
  s_password += random.choice(symbols)


for number in range(nr_numbers):
  n_password += random.choice(numbers)


final_pass = str(l_password) + str(s_password) + str(n_password)
print(f"Here is your password :{final_pass}")


#Hard Level - Order of characters randomised:
#e.g. 4 letter, 2 symbol, 2 number = g^2jk8&P
```

Comment: Note: To simplify your code, you can use `string.ascii_letters` and `string.digits`.  Nice, well thought out question / code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `random.shuffle` to shuffle the result:

```py
final_pass = str(l_password) + str(s_password) + str(n_password)
l = list(final_pass)
random.shuffle(l)
final_pass = ''.join(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample()`

```
import random
password = "123435454"
password = ''.join(random.sample(password, len(password)))
print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Both random.choice and random.shuffle

```
password = ""

for letter in range(nr_letters):
    password += random.choice(letters)

for symbol in range(nr_symbols):
    password += random.choice(symbols)

for number in range(nr_numbers):
    password += random.choice(numbers)

shuffle_password = list(password)

random.shuffle(shuffle_password)

print(''.join(shuffle_password))
```